# R alternate two/four vectors after every two/four values

Tags: r

Say I have two vectors with values that come from formulas:

```
A <- c(0.11, -0.11, -.20, .20, -0.18, 0.18)
B <- c(-0.11, 0.11, .20, -.20, 0.18, -0.18)
```

What I wish to accomplish is to merge the vertices into one vector where I have the first two values of A, then the 3rd and 4th value of B, then the 5th and 6th value of A (in the actual data set the vertices are 96 characters long), to end up with:

```
V <- c(0.11, -0.11, .20, -.20, -0.18, 0.18)
```

I wish to accomplish the same with four vectors where it switches between vectors every 4 values. Seeing as the vectors are long, I don't want to have to resort to the use of indices.

I've fumbled around a lot with combinations of the `c()` and `rbind()` functions, but always end up merging incorrectly.

An example of code I've tried (with called objects substituted with possible values):

```
c(rbind(1.2 - (1.2 + 1.2/2),
        1.2 - 1.2/2)),
  rbind(1.2 - 1.2/2), 
        1.2 - (1.2 + 1.2/2)))
```

This would end up with the vectors being merged after the first one ends. I've tried different combinations, but none worked out for me.

Does anybody have a nifty trick up their sleeve?

Comment: How would your desired result will look like for 4 vectors?

Comment: Say I have vectors:
`A <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)`

`B <- c(21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36)`

`C <- c(41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56)`

`D <- c(61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76)`

I would want the resulting vector to be:

`V <- c(1,2,3,4,25,26,27,28,49,50,51,52,73,74,75,76)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a wrapper function that will accept any number of vectors and give you desire result (though the vectors are assumed to be of same length)

```
Myfunc <- function(...){
  temp <- cbind(...)
  len <- ncol(temp)
  suppressWarnings(temp[cbind(seq(nrow(temp)), rep(seq(len), each = len))]) 
}

Myfunc(A, B)
## [1]  0.11 -0.11  0.20 -0.20 -0.18  0.18
```

---

On 4 vectors (Provided by OP in comments)

```
A <- 1:16  ; B <- 21:36 ; C <- 41:56 ; D <- 61:76
Myfunc(A, B, C, D)
## [1]  1  2  3  4 25 26 27 28 49 50 51 52 73 74 75 76
```

Answer (score 2):

```
> (1:6) %% 4 %in% c(1,2)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

> (1:12) %% 8 %in% c(1,2,3,4)
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

etc.

or for your example

```
> D <- rep(0,6)
> D[(1:6) %% 4 %in% c(1,2)] <- A[(1:6) %% 4 %in% c(1,2)]
> D[!(1:6) %% 4 %in% c(1,2)] <- B[!(1:6) %% 4 %in% c(1,2)]
> D
[1]  0.11 -0.11  0.20 -0.20 -0.18  0.18
```

Comment: another way to get those booleans which is probably not as cryptic `as.logical(rep(c(0,0,1,1),2))` and `as.logical(rep(c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1),2))`

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly for 2 vertices! But I'm having trouble converting it to 4. This is because instead of 2 types of boolean placements, I need 4.

By using `1:96 %% 16 %in% c(1,2,3,4)`, I can get the first vector to find correct placement. However, I can't use `!1:96 %% 16 %in% c(1,2,3,4)`, as it will fill all placements for the second vector, while I only want it to take the 4 characters right after the characters I've put in from the first vector. I've been tinkering since your reply and still haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: `E[0:95 %% 16 %in% 0:3] <- A[0:95 %% 16 %in% 0:3]`

`E[0:95 %% 16 %in% 4:7] <- B[0:95 %% 16 %in% 4:7]`

etc